# How to include PyInstaller inside a PyInstaller bundle?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I want to freeze a Python application that has, as one of its features, the ability to produce freezed Python applications using PyInstaller. Here is a minimal application showing what I want to achieve:

```py
import PyInstaller.__main__

with open('inception', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('import sys; print("Hello from the inside")\n')
PyInstaller.__main__.run(['--noconfirm', '--onedir', 'inception'])
```

Freezing this with PyInstaller

```bsh
PS> pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir example.py
```

should produce an executable `exemple.exe` that can be executed to produce `inception.exe`.

On the first try, I got the following error

```bsh
PS> .\dist\example\example.exe
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pywin32-ctypes
```

This was fixed by installing `pywin32` (`pywin32-ctypes` was already installed) and changing PyInstaller's `compat.py` file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639904/686806). Rebundling the application now results in the following error

```
PS> .\dist\example\example.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PyInstaller.__main__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\code\stackoverflow\pyinstaller_inception\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyInstaller' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[14376] Failed to execute script example
```

So it seems like PyInstaller does not bundle itself inside the application. There is an [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4651) on PyInstaller github page, but it does not really help. Is this even possible? If so, how?

This needs to run on Windows 10, with Python 3.7. I am using PyInstaller version 3.5.

Comment: The issue linked is not about including PyInstaller inside a PyInstaller bundle.

Answer (score 0):

From one of the PyInstaller dev:

> To do this you'd need a hook for PyInstaller - we don't have one and won't create one. You'd also need to mod the bootloader process, create runtime hooks, and loads more. We can't, won't and don't support or encourage this.

TL;DR: You can't do that with PyInstaller, one workaround is to use another software such as [nuitka](https://nuitka.net/) and [Pyoxidizer](https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io) or [Embed your app manually](https://docs.python.org/3.0/extending/embedding.html).